# Angular directive executing a function without using isolate scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that only fires a click event if the element it is on is clicked. I do not want the click event to fire if a child element is clicked. This is what I have so far and seems to be doing the trick.

```
bizi.directive('bbStrictClick', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            clicked: '&bbStrictClick'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.click(function (event) {
                if (event.target === element[0]) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    scope.clicked();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

]);

The problem is I am using isolate scope and as a result I cannot add this directive to elements that have other directives using isolate scope. Is there a way to execute the function specified in the directive attribute value without using isolate scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using $scope.$eval:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval

```
bizi.directive('bbStrictClick', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.click(function (event) {
                if (event.target === element[0]) {
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                    scope.$eval(attrs.bbStrictClick);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

You could also use $parse to pre-parse the expression into a function, and then execute that function (basically what `&` does).

EDIT: you could have a look at how ngClick is coded in angular's source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L49